# How to tell if an Angularjs page is loaded from a refresh or navigated to by link?

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

In Angularjs pages are loaded via ajax calls to templates, and the browser never reloads it's full content (a single app). However you can directly link to a page itself and Angularjs figures out which contents it needs to load.

How can I tell if a page has been directly linked to (maybe from a refresh) or if it was dynamically loaded (for example, when using `location.path('/somepath');`)?

I've tried looking in the docs and I haven't found anything. I can set a local storage variable, but that seems overkill.

Comment: I believe you're trying to solve the wrong problem. If you tell us what you're really trying to achieve, then we may provide an alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can know it before any Angular code. You can look to the `window.location` object and check the URL. For example, just do it before the `angular.module('myModule', [...])` line.

```
var url = window.location.href;

if (url.contains('/somepath')) {
    console.log('do something !');
}

angular.module('myModule', [...])
// Angular code goes on ...
```

Comment: If I were to refresh the page by holding `Command + R`, and I did that over and over again, nothing in there would tell me whether or not that page was arrived at by loading content dynamically or via a hard refresh. BTW I didn't downvote you.

Comment: If you hard refresh (or if you come from a external navigation), you'll pass on the code lines. If you are already in Angular, you'll never pass on this line. So you can say you are here from a hard refresh or a navigation. Just try it. Add a simple `console.log(...)` before your Angular module definition. You'll see the log only after a hard refresh or a true navigation.

Comment: Oh your right. If the page is loaded from a hard refresh you only hit that code once right?

Comment: Yes. This code is executed only once in the Single Page Application lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

Page is never actually refreshing itself. All files are preloaded into browser and then only thing refreshing is content. 
When you manually refresh the page angular loads again as it is the first time you open the page.